# Compiler wants mangled name from OpenCL.lib

Tags: c++, c, opencl, name-mangling

I try compile Intel OpenCL code. Program is simple:

```
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cl_int error = CL_SUCCESS;

   // Get platform number.
    cl_uint platformNumber = 0;

    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &platformNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

But not found `_clGetPlatformIDs@12`. I add OpenCL.lib and path. In OpenCL.lib is `clGetPlatformIDs`, not `_clGetPlatformIDs@12`.

How can I turn off name mangling?

Comment: The `cl.h` file already includes use of `extern "C"`, but you aren't getting it. Can you post your OS and compiler versions along with your compile command line?

Comment: Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As and renaming Main.cpp to Main.c nothing do

Comment: I compile under Windows in Visual C++ Express 2010

Comment: I get this problem too.  This is not a case of missing extern "C" I don't know how OpenCL.lib could ever work with Visual Studio.  The header uses __stdcall which tells the compiler to prefix with underscore then add the @12.  _cdecl would prefix with an underscore.  I know of no way to tell MSVC to have no prefix at all.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx

Comment: @Borneq _'But not found _clGetPlatformIDs@12'_ Please post the exact linker error you get, and the relevant code, where the error occurs.

Comment: Where did you get that `OpenCL.lib` file? I'm able to compile and link your code with the [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-tools-sdks/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've got any clue about the `opencl` library, but simply writing

```
extern "C" {
    #include <CL/cl.h>
}
```

could probably help to solve the C/C++ name mangling collisions.

Comment: In cl.h is #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

Comment: @Borneq Your exact context is still unclear. Improve your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default calling convention to `cdecl`. In Visual Studio, this is in the project properties Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced pane.

Comment: cdecl puts an underscore in front of the names.  The cl.h header file declares the methods as __stdcall anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are linking to the wrong version of the library.  There should be an x86 (Win32) version and an x64 version.  By default, VS2013 creates x86 (Win32) C++ applications.  Either switch libraries, or change your project to x64.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx.